# How to empirically check properties of bootstrapped sample mean

Tags: r, machine-learning, bootstrap

**Problem Setting:**
Consider the situation that we observe $X = (x_1, x_2,...,x_N)$ i.i.d from the distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. We denote the sample mean as $\bar{x}$ and let $\bar{x}_b^{\star}$ (for $b = 1,2,...,B$) denote $B$ bootstrapping sample mean. Hence, each $\bar{x}_b^{\star}$ includes $x_1, x_2,...,x_N$ by sampling with replacement from $X$.
Then we can obtain that:
(1). **Var($\bar{x}_b^{\star}$):**
\begin{aligned}
Var(\bar{x}_{b}^{\star}) 
&= E[Var(\bar{x}_b^{\star}|X)] + Var[E(\bar{x}_b^{\star}|X)]\\
&= E(\frac{N-1}{N^2}S^2) + Var(\bar{X})\\
&= \frac{2N-1}{N^2}\sigma^2,
\end{aligned}
where $S^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum(x_j - \bar{x})^2$.
Therefore, $Var(\bar{x}_{b}^{\star}) = \frac{2N-1}{N^2}\sigma^2$.
(2). **Cov($\bar{x}_1^{\star}$,$\bar{x}_2^{\star}$):**
\begin{aligned}
Cov(\bar{x}_1^{\star}, \bar{x}_2^{\star}) &= Cov(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_1^{(i)}, \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_2^{(i)})\\
&= \frac{1}{N^2}Cov(\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_1^{(i)}, \sum_{i=1}^{N}x_2^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j}Cov(x_1^{(i)}, x_2^{(i)})\\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{N}.
\end{aligned}
Therefore, $Cov(\bar{x}_1^{\star}, \bar{x}_2^{\star}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}$.
(3). **Var($\bar{x}_{bag}$) where $\bar{x}_{bag} = \frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^{B}\bar{x}_b^{\star}:$**
\begin{aligned}
Var(\bar{x}_{bag}) &= \rho\sigma^2 + \frac{1-\rho}{B}\sigma^2\\
&= \frac{N}{2N-1}\sigma^2 + \frac{1 - \frac{N}{2N-1}}{B}\sigma^2\\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{2N-1}\frac{N(B+1)-1}{BN},
\end{aligned}
since $\rho = Corr(\bar{x}_1^{\star}, \bar{x}_2^{\star}) = \frac{N}{2N-1}$.
**Once we obtain these theorotical properties, how can we simulate some data to show them? I try to set up a basic simulation setting like**

```
N <- 200
mu <- 1
sigma_2 <- 4
X <- rnorm(N, mean = mu, sd = 2) # mean = 1, sd = 2
Xbar <- mean(X)
varXbar <- sigma_2/N
```

**But I struggle with the evaluation of bootstrapped properties.**